# integrating snakemake in nextflow workflow management system

Tags: snakemake, nextflow

I am trying to work with a data analysis pipeline which is made in `snakemake` (and source code is not available). But for technical reasons (according to our hpc policy we are not allowed to install anything on the hpc) I cannot run it using `snakemake` (we do not have it installed on the `HPC`) but I have to run it in `nextflow` (which is the only workflow management system we have). In fact I have to run `snakemake` in `nextflow`. developers mentioned that the tool is available on `bioconda`:

```
mamba install -c conda-forge -c bioconda drop
```

and can be run using snakemake for example using this command:

```
snakemake aberrantExpression --cores 10
```

Do you have any experience how to install such tool in `nextflow` and `integrate/run` `snakemake` in `nextflow`?

Answer (score 0):

> But for technical reasons I cannot run it using snakemake (we do not have it installed on the HPC

It should be possible to install `snakemake` using `pip` (or using `conda` on `bioconda` channel):

```sh
pip install snakemake
```

OR

```sh
mamba install -c conda-forge -c bioconda snakemake
```

Comment: according to our hpc we are not allowed to install anything on the hpc. this is their policy

Comment: Hmm, so the admins do not allow creation of private environments or using docker/singularity?

Comment: actually we can use singularity (it is installed). what do you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

If conda is available for nextflow, you can create environments for each single process. Either by providing `environment.yml` files or specifying conda packages directly in the process. Those environments will be created in the `-work-dir` in a specific subdirectory `conda`.

In your case you could write a process like this

```java
process aberrantExpr {
    conda "${baseDir}/environment.yml", useMamba: true
    input:
        tuple file(input1), file(input2), ..., file(inputN)
    output:
        tuple file(youroutputs)
    shell:
    """
    snakemake aberrantExpression --cores 10
    """
```

note that ${baseDir} refers to the directory where your `main.nf` is located.

while your `environment.yml` should look like this:

```yaml
name: yourenv
channels:
    - conda-forge
    - bioconda
dependencies:
    - snakemake
    - drop
```

For further reading check out the [docs of nextflow / Section conda](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/conda.html)

However, I think that your entire approach does not make sense. While you can wrap basically every command in nextflow, it will not create specific subprocesses from a snakemake pipeline. The entire snakemake pipeline will be treated as a single nextflow process after all. If you are not planning to parallelize this process on multiple inputs or add further pre- or post-processing steps it might be easier to create your conda environment manually before and wrap your command in a shell script like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
source /path/to/conda/bin/activate /path/to/your/env

snakemake aberrantExpression --cores 10
```